# MicrosoftGraph/RestAPI: Proper urls/parameters to headless login to use Outlook Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

(this is for a Raspberry Pi / UWP, but using RestAPI) - using a clientId and an appSecret, what's the proper paths to use to eventually access a user's Calendar. (This use case CAN use the username/password of the user).

I already can do it except that it requires a dialog username/password signin. On the Raspberry Pi (even with a screen), this fails to even display a dialog for signin.

Looking at the documents for service/daemon app / app-only, it requires a tenantId. My use is not for work/school, but personal Outlook.com, so no tenant.
(ref: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only)

Other suggested calls to login.microsoftonline.com return bad requests.

Would appreciate (proper) doc referral, and better yet, working code to simply auth.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Current Insider builds of Windows IoT Core DO allow for username/password challenge auth (requires screen). And, current builds do not yet allow for headless authentication.

Using the username/password dialog challenge, the normal Microsoft Graph Rest api's work...

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar